How does health scaling with stats work in Dead Cells?
Dead Cells has stat boosters called Scrolls of Power, which allow you to upgrade one out of two/three stats (depending on the type of Scroll you find).

As you can see in the image, they might say something like “+70% health”. However, if you never choose one Scroll type (let’s say Survival), then choose it much later when your health is ~10,000, you won’t suddenly gain ~7,000 health. You’ll gain a lot, yes, but nowhere near that much.
So how exactly does health scale with Scrolls of Power?

It should give you 7k though, as that is 70% of your 10k HP.

@matszwecja That’s not how health scaling works (in this game anyway).

Do you have specific values proving that it does not work that way?

@matszwecja The below answer by pinckerman, which sources the Dead Cells wiki.

Quote from Dead Cells wiki: "The Survival stat is the largest factor in determining the size of the player's health pool (gives 70% extra health for second Survival level)." pinckerman's answer does not contradict that.

To determine the player's max health, the player's base health (100) is multiplied by 3 separate values, which rely on the current level of Brutality, Tactics, and Survival that the player currently has. Each color grants a different relative percentage of health increase:

Survival: the highest upgrade, adds ~70HP for each upgrade
Brutality: adds 65% for second Brutality level and then less, up until 35 levels
Tactics: the lowest upgrade, adds 50% for second Tactics level and then less, up until 25 levels

The complete multipliers are available at this Dead Cells wiki page
